# wp_query that match most of the tags in single post

Tags: php, wordpress

I need help in getting related post using multiple tags.

I have Post with the tags **poetry, motivational, attitude, rules, lines, sigma,inspirations**

I wanted wp_query that matche most of these tags.

Note: Note every post has these all tags.

I am working on the site [ntAfzal](https://www.ntafzal.com/)

Answer (score 0):

You can list all your post tags into an array and list the posts which belongs to that tags as below.

```
$tags = array("poetry", "motivational", "attitude", "rules", "lines", "sigma", "inspirations");
$query = new WP_Query(
    [
        'tax_query' => [
            [
                'taxonomy' => 'post_tag',
                'terms'    => $tags,
                'compare'  => 'IN',
            ]
        ],
    ]
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can match most of the tags using `tag__in`.

```
$post_tags = array("poetry", "motivational", "attitude", "rules", "lines", "sigma", "inspirations");

$query = new WP_Query( array( 'tag__in' => $post_tags  ) );
```

Here I added code for your reference and also you can see the documentation in WordPress for [wp_query with tag parameters.](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/#tag-parameters)